# How is the Hessian defined under a different metric + definition?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am reading on wikiedpia and the definition of Hessian

> $\mbox{Hess}(f)=\nabla_i\, \partial_j f \ dx^i \!\otimes\! dx^j = \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}-\Gamma_{ij}^k \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k} \right) dx^i \otimes dx^j $

1. So I am just wondering, where is the Christoffel symbols coming from? If $f$ is defined on $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$, do I just let $\Gamma_{ij}^{k} = 0$? Because if I have something simple like $f = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)$, wouldn't i just get back to $\ 1dx^i \!\otimes\! dx^j$
2. What happens if I change the metric? I supposed that would be reflected in the Christoffel symbols.

1(i) To make this question less abstract, take $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb R$, and if possible could someone show me an example of how its calculated? Assume we have the standard Euclidean Metric.

2(i). Let's just say it's still $\Bbb R^2$, and make a new metric $g = \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} (dx^2 + dy^2)$.